# Request header and JSON parsing in Android Retrofit

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit2

I'm trying to learn Retrofit and use it in the project I have right now. I have successfully implemented some basic GET and POST methods, but right now I am stuck trying to add information to the header of my request.

This is the Client class:

```
public class CategoryClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "URL is here";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

This is the interface with the GET method:

```
public interface CategoryService {

    @GET("/v3/projects/{projectId}/categories/")
    Call<CategoryResponse> getProjectCategories(@Query("projectId") String projectId);
}
```

This is my Category class:

```
public class Category2 {

    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String _id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("tasks")
    private int tasks;

    public Category2(String _id, String name, int tasks) {

        this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }


    public String get_id(){
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_id(String _id){
        this._id = _id;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }
    public void setTasks(int tasks){
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

This is my CategoryResponse class (where I get the list of categories from the request):

```
public class CategoryResponse {

    private List<Category2> results;

    public List<Category2> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Category2> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

And this is me calling it from my Activity:

```
categoryService =
                CategoryClient.getClient().create(CategoryService.class);

        Call<CategoryResponse> call = categoryService.getProjectCategories(projectId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Response<CategoryResponse> response) {

                int statusCode = response.code();
                categoriesList2 = new ArrayList<>();
                categoriesList2 = response.body().getResults();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
```

I need to add a token in the header of the request, but this token will change constantly so I can not use it above my interface with "@Header". Is there any way to add this header from my Activity?

Comment: have u tried using interceptors ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How can I do it using an Interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your interface modify your method with @Header

```
@GET("/v3/projects/{projectId}/categories/")
Call<CategoryResponse> getProjectCategories(@Query("projectId") String 
projectId, @Header("Token") String token);
```

Later you can call this method from your activity:

```
String token = "someRandomtoken";
categoryService =
            CategoryClient.getClient().create(CategoryService.class);

    Call<CategoryResponse> call = categoryService.getProjectCategories(projectId, token);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Response<CategoryResponse> response) {

            int statusCode = response.code();
            categoriesList2 = new ArrayList<>();
            categoriesList2 = response.body().getResults();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. If I want to add a key to the header, which would be "Authorization" and after the token, what do I do?

Comment: I am not sure , but you can try adding extra perimeter with  @Header

Answer (score 2):

I am working with the same scenario where I have to change the token each day and for each new user ofcourse, Interceptors will help you creating the header request and you can add it to the http client while building it.

Since your scenario is quite similar to mine, I have added my scenario here which I use and works perfect for me.

If you want to understand more about it [refer here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors).

```
      Interceptor interceptorSecure = chain -> {


        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .method(original.method(), original.body());

        requestBuilder.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        requestBuilder.header("Origin", ORIGIN_URL);
        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
      };

      //after that use this to http client builder
      //add it to your httpClientBuilder
      yourHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(interceptorSecure);
      OkHttpClient client = yourHttpClientBuilder.build();

      //this is your retrofit builder, the way you have built with base url and gson convertors..
      Retrofit retrofit = yourRetrofitBuilder.client(client).build();
      retrofit.create(CategoryService.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I have to put the Interceptor inside my Activity or should I create another class for it? Also, how can I call this Interceptor and get the response from the "getGetProjectCategories" defined in the CategoryService interface?

Comment: you can create interceptor anywhere, I suggest create it where you build your http client and add it there only with the required headers..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do I access the response from the call? In the code you posted I only have "retrofit.create(CategoryService.class)". What do I have to do to call the method "getProjectCategories" inside this class and get the results?

Comment: this gives you the retrofit instance with your header and etc parameter requirements now after you get this instance you can call your method to get response..

Comment: What is "yourHttpClientBuilder" and "yourRetrofitBuilder"? I am facing difficulties trying to understand what I have to do.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example so I can see how it works, please?